# How to mock a particular method of a spring bean

Tags: spring, junit, mockito

I have a spring bean with multiple APIs. Mocking the bean doesn't serve my purpose as I would like to verify fetchFromDb() called only once on multiple calls to getCachedData() with the same input. This is to make sure the result is cached.

Is it possible to mock fetchFromDb() on bean 'market' while calling getCachedData()?

**Sample Class**

```
@Configuration("market")
public class AllMarket {

@Autowired
private CacheManager cachedData;

public boolean getCachedData(LocalDate giveDate) {
   //check if it exists in cache
   if(Objects.nonNull(checkCache(giveDate)) {
      return checkCache(giveDate);
   }
   //fetch from database
   boolean bool = fetchFromDb(givenDate);
   cacheData(giveDate, bool);
   return bool;
}
public boolean checkCache(LocalDate giveDate) {
   return cacheManager.getData(givenDate); 
}
public boolean fetchFromDb(LocalDate givenDate) {
  //return the data from database
} 
public void cacheData(LocalDate givenDate, boolean bool) {
   cacheManager.addToCache(givenDate, bool);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Mockito.spy()` for this kind of test. In this case you should spy your `AllMarket` instance and stub `fetchFromDb`. At the end you can `Mockito.verify` that `fetchFromDb` was called exactly once. It will look something like this:

```
AllMarket spy = spy(allMarket);
when(spy.fetchFromDb(givenDate)).thenReturn(true); //you have boolean as a return type
...
verify(spy, times(1)).fetchFromDb(givenDate);
```

For more information, you can see [Official Mockito doc](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.24.5/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe mockito argument captor could asist you. It lets you to capture method input and how many times method was called, also may other functions. Please check https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-annotations.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link. It didn't help as as I need to assert how many elements are there in cachedData object. My requirement is to mock the fetchFromDb() so that it won't prompt to hit the database.